# Unexpected behaviour using Filter in QGIS 3.2

Tags: qgis-3, filter

I have encountered an unexpected difference in how the Filter function works in QGIS 3.2 to previous versions (2.14 for example).

I used the Filter function to select a set of features based on a variable value; in QGIS 2.14 I ended up with an attribute table with the following header:[image: QGIS 2.14 filteed table header]

Using exactly the same shapefile in QGIS 3.2, I found the following:
[image: QGIS 3.2 filtered table header]

As a result, in QGIS 3.2 selecting an individual feature selected all the features in the filtered dataset (it appears to treat the filtered data as a single feature). In QGIS 2.14, I am able to select individual features from the filtered dataset.

I was able to get round this by using Select by Expression in this case, however, I use the Filter function a lot and would like to know
if this is a known issue? and has the function of the Filter function been intentionally changed?

ETA:
I have investigated this further in QGIS 3.2 and split the original shapefile into single parts (Multi-part to single parts). This affected ~150 of the 380000 features. I then re-filtered the data but observed the same behaviour as above. In the full dataset, individual features can be selected.

ETA the expression used to filter:
"AttributeName" = 'TextValue'
This expression worked using Select by Expression.

Comment: I'm not getting the problem...could you add the filter expression you used?